# Google Cloud Kubernetes - How to create Zonal or Regional GKE cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

How do I know if I'm using Zonal or Regional when using the following terraform code? I want Zonal since GCP doesn't charge `GKE Management fees` when using Zonal GKE cluster.

But I'm not sure if the following is Zonal or Regional?

```
resource "google_container_cluster" "primary" {
  name     = "my-gke-cluster"
  network            = "default"
  location               = "europe-west1"
  initial_node_count = 1
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

Google Kubernetes Engine defines the regional as multiple-zonal. For a zone, it is indicated by an alphabet, like `a`, `b`, `c`.

So, here are the examples for the location.

- Regional/Multiple-zonal: `europe-west1`, `us-west1`, etc.
- Zonal: `europe-west1-b`, `us-west1-a`, etc.

In your terraform module, if you want to have zonal GKE cluster, it looks like this.

```
resource "google_container_cluster" "primary" {
  name               = "zonal-cluster"
  network            = "default"
  location           = "europe-west1-b"
  initial_node_count = 1
}
```